# 3mf circles are printing as polygons

Tags: prusa-i3, stl, fusion360, prusaslicer

When I'm using a .3mf file from Fusion 360 the circles are coming out as polygonal shapes that are very easy to see.

When using a .stl file from Fusion 360 the circles are near perfect the polygons that make it up are small enough that you can't see.

Is there any way to fix this in Fusion 360 to export the file properly or is it a problem related to PrusaSlicer?

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies in Fusion 360.

If you export using file export as .3mf then the refinement (poly count) is set to low. Thus it creates a low-quality circle.

If you export through the mesh tab, select 32d print and make sure the refinement is high then it exports a nice-looking perfect circle.

Comment: You seem to have quickly found your own solution. Please don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted answer, when the system allows you to, [in 48 hours](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/#:~:text=Wait%2048%20hours.,can%20accept%20your%20own%20answer.), in order to remove the question from the unanswered queue. Many thanks.

Comment: My understanding is all slicers will represent circles as polygons.  It's a matter of if they put enough sides on the polygon that it looks like a circle when it prints.